Testing concurrency of a collection with XUnit provides different results
I have a concurrent class called ClientManager that uses a hashset and a ReadWriterLock to register my "clients" through their Guid:
internal class ClientManager : IClientManager
{
    private readonly HashSet<Guid> _clients = new HashSet<Guid>();
    private readonly ReaderWriterLock _lock = new ReaderWriterLock();

    public IEnumerable<Guid> Clients
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                _lock.AcquireReaderLock(100.Milliseconds());
                var result = _clients.ToList();
                return result;
            }
            finally
            {
                _lock.ReleaseReaderLock();
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddClient(Guid clientId, string login, string appName)
    {
        try
        {
            _lock.AcquireWriterLock(100.Milliseconds());
            _clients.Add(clientId);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ReleaseWriterLock();
        }
    }

    public void RemoveClient(Guid clientId)
    {
        try
        {
            _lock.AcquireWriterLock(100.Milliseconds());
            _clients.Remove(clientId);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ReleaseWriterLock();
        }
    }
}

I created a unit test that uses three tasks to access the hashset / add clients / remove clients. At the end of the unit test, i expect to have 0 entries left in the hashset:
    [Fact]
    public void ClientManager_Should_Handle_Concurent_Operations()
    {
        var clientManager = new ClientManager();
        var isDoneAdding = false;
        var addTask = new Task(() =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                //Adding client should enter write lock
                clientManager.AddClient(Guid.NewGuid(), $"login_{i}", $"appName_{i}");
            }

            isDoneAdding = true;
        });

        var accessTask = new Task(() =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
              //Getting clients should enter read lock
               var clients = clientManager.Clients;
            }
        });

        var removeTask = new Task(() =>
        {

            for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                var existingGuid = clientManager.Clients.FirstOrDefault();
               if (existingGuid != default)
               {
                   //Removing client should enter write lock
                   clientManager.RemoveClient(existingGuid);
               }
            }

            //refactor that
            while (clientManager.Clients.Count() > 0 && isDoneAdding)
            {
                var existingGuid = clientManager.Clients.FirstOrDefault();
                if (existingGuid != default)
                {
                    clientManager.RemoveClient(existingGuid);
                }
            }
        });

        accessTask.Start();
        addTask.Start();
        removeTask.Start();

        Task.WaitAll(accessTask, addTask, removeTask);
        Assert.True(clientManager.Clients.Count() == 0);
    }

The unit test always fails:
Failing test
I changed the hashset and lock system for a ConcurrentDictionary like so:
internal class ClientManager : IClientManager
{
    //We don't need the value here so just put a byte to reduce memory footprint
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, byte> _clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, byte>();
    private readonly ReaderWriterLock _lock = new ReaderWriterLock();

    public IEnumerable<Guid> Clients
    {
        get
        {
            return _clients.Keys;
        }
    }

    public void AddClient(Guid clientId, string login, string appName)
    {
        _clients.TryAdd(clientId, default);
    }

    public void RemoveClient(Guid clientId)
    {
        _clients.Remove(clientId, out _);
    }
}

The unit test succeeded 320 times in a row: Successful test
I don't understand what I'm missing with the hashset lock system for it to work, can someone help me understand what's going on?

Please note that in your test nothing guarantees that addTask finishes first (isDoneAdding is used incorrectly). Add some delay to addTask and it will fail with ConcurrentDictionary, too. Btw. ReaderWriterLock is slower than a normal lock so use it only when the critical section takes long enough time to compensate the overhead. If you just need a fast thread-safe HashSet<T> you can try my ThreadSafeHashSet<T>. See some details here.

​100.Milliseconds() -- What is this?

There are many issues, but the root cause of why this particular test is not passing is that code that you marked to refactor:
while (clientManager.Clients.Count() > 0 && isDoneAdding) {
    var existingGuid = clientManager.Clients.FirstOrDefault();
    if (existingGuid != default) {
        clientManager.RemoveClient(existingGuid);
    }
}

needs to be written as this:
//still refactor that
while (!isDoneAdding) ; // spinwait for the adding to end 
while (clientManager.Clients.Count() > 0 ) {
    var existingGuid = clientManager.Clients.FirstOrDefault();
    if (existingGuid != default) {
        clientManager.RemoveClient(existingGuid);
    }
}

Further issues:

ReaderWriterLock is deprecated in favor of ReaderWriterLockSlim
You are returning a copy (ToList) in IEnumerable<Guid> Clients which will quickly become stale.

I suspect this is why your original implementation "fails". The remove task gets an empty list much more often which given this check before removing/contending/locking if (existingGuid != default) { causes its 10_000 iterations to finish more quickly than the add task. So when the remove task checks for isDoneAdding it's still false and consequently doesn't enter the loop to remove all still-not-removed items. This logically gives us a final Count of > 0.


Your tests should be concerned with measuring that a non-deterministic number of writes/accesses happens concurrently, not that we can drain the structure successfully.

If not for educational purposes, I'd research to find a battle-tested implementation of ConcurrentHashSet somewhere. Maybe the one suggested by
György Kőszeg in the comments: ThreadSafeHashSet<T>

This is not a direct answer to you question. I just want to point out two flaws in your code, that would have to be addressed if you intend to use it in a production environment:
try
{
    _lock.AcquireWriterLock(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    _clients.Add(clientId);
}
finally
{
    _lock.ReleaseWriterLock();
}

The AcquireWriterLock should be called before entering the try/catch block. In case of timeout, the AcquireWriterLock will throw without acquiring the lock. You don't want to release the lock if it hasn't been acquired.
bool isDoneAdding = false;

You are using the isDoneAdding variable to coordinate actions in a multithreaded environment, without synchronization. You are not allowed to do that. If you do, your program has undefined behavior. To fix this, you can either replace the bool variable with a CancellationTokenSource, or stick with the bool but access it with volatile semantics:
Volatile.Write(ref isDoneAdding, true);

while (clientManager.Clients.Count() > 0 && Volatile.Read(ref isDoneAdding))

